# inserting a bulk list to mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

i have got a text file. there are names on every lines. here is a sample view:

```
.
.
.
Oakes
Oakley
Obadiah
Obelix
Oberon
Obert
Obiajulu
.   
.
.
```

i wanna insert them to mysql by using php. i created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE names (                                 
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                   
            name int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                               
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
          )
```

could you please kindly suggest me a function to make this job? thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$strings = explode("\n", file_get_contents('your.txt'));
```

then loop on $strings to generate your query.